# Read data from Excel file incrementally for automated smoke test in Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium

I m trying to automate smoke test for my web application using Selenium Webdriver. I want to run these tests twice in a day. I have created a java class TestData.java under my testcases package. My code is given below:

I want to read data from excel incrementally from the previous build. Suppose if data is read from Cell A2 in excel in the first build, on the next smoke test run, data needs to be read from Cell A3 in excel. Can anyone give me a code snippet which i can use?

```java
package qa.com.test.testcases;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.NumberToTextConverter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class TestData {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "resource" })
    public ArrayList<String> dataSetUp(String testcaseName, String testCaseMode) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> saveDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(projectPath + "/excel/Testdata.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        int sheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int i = 0; i < sheets; i++) {
            System.out.print(testCaseMode);
            if (workbook.getSheetName(i).equalsIgnoreCase(testCaseMode)) {

                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.iterator();
                Row firstrow = rows.next();
                Iterator<Cell> ce = firstrow.cellIterator();
                int k = 0;
                int column = 0;
                while (ce.hasNext()) {
                    Cell value = ce.next();

                    if (value.getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Testcase")) {
                        column = k;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                while (rows.hasNext()) {
                    Row r = rows.next();
                    if (r.getCell(column).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase(testcaseName)) {
                        Iterator<Cell> cv = r.cellIterator();
                        while (cv.hasNext()) {
                            Cell c = cv.next();
                            if (c.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
                                saveDataList.add(c.getStringCellValue());
                            } else {
                                saveDataList.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(c.getNumericCellValue()));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return saveDataList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though not a clean solution, but you can add a check on the time. Say, if current time is before 1 pm, read from A2 else read from A3 assuming 1st run is always before 1pm and 2nd is always after 1pm.

Comment: might use a .properties file saved to current user directory... store row# and cell# and rollover when it gets to the end: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html